# Replace words with Javascript without removing the image

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace the words ”morrhåren” with ”skägget” in this p-tag. I’m not supposed to change anything in the HTML-kod, only in my js-file. How can I manage to change these words using Javascript and not making the image disappear?
[The HTML-kod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMdeX.png)

```
<p><img src=”http://blogg.wikki.se/wp-content/upploads/2009/06/catbyBaikal.jpg” align=”right”>
Är <span>katt</span>en skrämd lägger den morrhåren bakåt, detsamma gör den vid slagsmål för att skydda morrhåren. Om <span>katt</span>en är en nyfiken vinklar den morrhåren framåt.<p>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the innerHTML property of your `<p>` element  (`document.getElementById("/**enter id of your <p> element*/").innerHTML`) to fetch (by assigning it to a variable) or to set (by assigning a new string value to the property) the entire content of any HTML element.

Comment: I am not supposed to change anything in the HTML-kod. I must make the word replacement in the Javascript. The p-tag has no id.

Comment: Oh, that's true. Then `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()` is another way to reference the `<p>` element.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple `innerHTML` replacement (`p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/morrhåren/g, "skägget")`, where `p` is a reference to the element), which wouldn't make the image disappear (the `img` element would just get removed and replaced with a new one for the same image), but I'm going to assume there's some reason you shouldn't do that (for instance: an event handler on the `img` element) since you've made a point of saying you need to leave the `img` element alone.

If that's the case, you'll need to go through the `p`'s child nodes and operate only on the text nodes (`nodeType` === 3), updating their `nodeValue` (the text of the text node). If the target word only appears at the top level, you only need to go through the `p`'s child nodes; if it appears inside other elements in the `p`, you'll need a recursive function.

For instance, assuming `p` is a reference to that element:

```
for (var child = p.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
    if (child.nodeType === 3) {
        child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(/morrhåren/g, "skägget");
    }
}
```

Again, if you needed to handle descendant elements, you'd need to add recursion to that.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    var p = document.querySelector("p");
    for (var child = p.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3) {
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(/morrhåren/g, "skägget");
        }
    }
}, 800);
```

```html
<p><img src=”http://blogg.wikki.se/wp-content/upploads/2009/06/catbyBaikal.jpg” align=”right”>
Är <span>katt</span>en skrämd lägger den morrhåren bakåt, detsamma gör den vid slagsmål för att skydda morrhåren. Om <span>katt</span>en är en nyfiken vinklar den morrhåren framåt.<p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But, I think this is a bit to complicated for me... (var child = p.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) What shall i write here? In body I have button, H1, p, H2, H3, p, H2, p, H2, p (the last p i this row - what child is it?) etc.

Comment: @LindaFredrikson: What do you mean "what do I write here"? I showed you exactly what to write. Re finding the correct paragraph: That will depend on your page. Use any valid CSS selector with `document.querySelector` (or give it an ID and use `document.getElementById`).

Comment: I give up, this is to complicated for me. But thank you for trying!

Comment: Yes! Now it works! I wrote [3] in the code: (var child = p[3].firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling). Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @LindaFredrikson: If it's the *last* one, rather than a hardcoded index, I'd use `length - 1`: `var list = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); for (var child = list[list.length - 1].firstChild; ...`

Comment: It is not the last one... It works fine, so I am satisfied. Thank you very much. Have a nice day!