# How can I replace every single character on a page to a new one with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Chrome Extension and would like to replace all the content on the page to a different one.

For instance, I want to replace this:

```
<p class="ok">This is <u>a</u> test</p>
```

into this:

```
<p class="ok">Xaze ze <u>t</u> xmex</p>
```

Rule:

```
T > X
h > a
i > z
t > x
e > m
s > e
```

This is for making the page look totally unreadable but keep all the features and layout remained (though there would be some changes). I am thinking of a robust way to do this without breaking the HTML.

I have tried `.html()` and `.text()` but it doesn't look perfect. The trouble is it's hard to look up the `<u>a</u>` in a `<p></p>`. And I believe when in a real page, the trouble would be even bigger.

Any advice on this?

Thanks,

Comment: This is probably easier than you think it is. :-) See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189284/157247), for instance. Then just use a regular expression to do the actual text change. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks very much, but what if my HTML is a very complicated one and not only `p` in that section?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the HTML is complex.